# How I can wrap nested maps into list and write it recursive till last of element of json?

Tags: json, scala, jackson

Hi guys I have some odd json and need to convert it to type that will allow spark parse it. So I decided to use jackson lib to load it as value. So the jackson creates for me something Like this:

> Map(A-> Map(B-> Map(C-> C, CC-> CC, CCC-> CCC, CCCC-> , CCCC-> Map(D-> ....

Now what I need to do is convert whole structure that each map will be wrapped to List :

> Map(A-> List(Map(B-> List(Map(C-> C, CC-> CC, CCC-> CCC, CCCC-> CCCC) List(Map(D-> ....

I have tried something like this but this only helps me only for first value. Also I need to check if this is a Map of cause sometimes it could be List which I don't want to wrap

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val parsedJson = mapper.readValue[Map[String, Object]](j)

val b = parsedJson.map {
case (k,v) if v.isInstanceOf[Map[String, Object]] => (k,List(v))
}
```

Have you guys any idea how I can do this recursively that afterall my Json will be look like this:

```
{
  "A":[{
    "B":[{
       "C":"C",
       "CC":"CC",
       "CCC":"CCC"
    }]
  }]
}

{ //and not like that
  "A":{
    "B":{
       "C":"C",
       "CC":"CC",
       "CCC":"CCC"
    }
  }
}
```

**ANSWER** If we wan't to map List(Map(k -> Map(k -> v))) this is my solution with @Dima help

```
def wrapIt(m: Map[String, Any]): Map[String, Any] = m.map {
case (k, v: Map[String, Any]) => k -> List(wrapIt(v))
case (k, v: List[Map[String, Any]]) => k -> v.map(m => m.map {
    case (l, p: Map[String, Any]) => l -> List(wrapIt(p))
    case lp => lp
  })
case kv => kv
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to do the recursive part :)

```
 def wrapIt(m: Map[String, Any]): Map[String, Any] = m.map {
   case (k, v: Map[String, Any]) => k -> List(wrapIt(v))
   case kv => kv //                           ^^^^^^^ - magic!
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is what I needed !